# VCD dump (VHDL simulation with vcs )

Tags: vhdl

I need help in simulating VHDL code with VCS. What are options available to dump vcd file with vcs for vhdl code .I have tried all the options, which i found on internet. None seems to be working, or i am not doing it in a correct way . A detailed answer would be helpful
Commands tried till now:

```
    vcs test_top -R +vcs+vcdpluson -debug_pp
    vcs test_top -R +vcs+vcdpluson -debug_pp -vcd test.vcd
    vcs test_top -R +vcs+vcdpluson+vcd_file test.vcd -debug_pp
    vcs test_top -V -R +vcs+vcdpluson -debug_pp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to run the simv command as described in [this](http://userwww.sfsu.edu/necrc/files/synopsys%20tutorials/VCS_tutorial.counterexample.pdf) on page 3.